# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Freelancing Stack Exchange](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to respond to "Are your rates negotiable?"](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/how-to-respond-to-are-your-rates-negotiable)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Non disclosure agreement?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/non-disclosure-agreement)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are proper manners when delivering project after agreed date?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/what-are-proper-manners-when-delivering-project-after-agreed-date)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do open source projects come up with their sponsorship prices?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/how-do-open-source-projects-come-up-with-their-sponsorship-prices)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How Much Information is Enough Information?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/how-much-information-is-enough-information)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is a single page site better for SEO and visitors, or is a site with various pages better?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/is-a-single-page-site-better-for-seo-and-visitors-or-is-a-site-with-various-pag)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [how can I get references from my freelance editors when looking for a job?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-get-references-from-my-freelance-editors-when-looking-for-a-job)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Quotation not favorable (against me) to write software features](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/quotation-not-favorable-against-me-to-write-software-features)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When outsourcing freelance work to foreign country, do I file a 1065, a 1099/1042(S)?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/when-outsourcing-freelance-work-to-foreign-country-do-i-file-a-1065-a-1099-104)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Person didn't pay yet took the app and put it online](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/person-didnt-pay-yet-took-the-app-and-put-it-online)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have mentioned this here earlier, but **[I've left some notes in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17456258#17456258)**. (Don't worry, no one is in the room but me; chat isn't as scary as it sounds. You should check it out).

When I was reviewing the questions, I left my notes in the chat room for others to see my thought process behind each one.  I also edited titles to make the posts easier to find, and used various keywords to help others with similar problems find those valuable resources.

I also closed one or two of them that just weren't a good fit for our site.

These self-eval review periods are a great time for us to come together as the Freelancing SE community and make a positive impact on some posts that we may have forgotten about, but that other people on the Internet are coming across daily. We have the tools to make our site the best resource for freelancing problems!